# Remove Action for Review Order Title (Your order) in WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I am trying to remove the title "Your order" from the WooCommerce checkout without editing the template. Here's what I've tried, without success.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review_heading', 'youroder_remove_title');
function yourorder_remove_title() {
echo '';
}

remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review_heading', 10 );
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: You just need to override the template `checkout/form-checkout.php` via your active theme *(where "Your order" title is located)*… see and read: [Template structure & Overriding templates via a theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)

Comment: damn :) it should be available through hook.

Comment: Not for html changes like this (as you need to remove the heading tags too).

Answer (score 1):

add this to your function.php to remove ordor summary from checkout

remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'woocommerce_order_review', 10 );